# Going to a ViewController with a custom segue causes viewWillAppear to get called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have written a custom segue, because i wanted to add my own animations to it. Everything works alright, besides the fact that the viewDidLoad method in the target view CiewController gets called twice. Here is the perform method for my segue:

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController* sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    CGPoint originalCenter = destinationViewController.view.center;
    destinationViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.originatingPoint.x * 3, self.originatingPoint.y);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
        delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
        animations:^{
            destinationViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
        }];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

[----- EDIT -----]

The segue is present in the storyboard as a custom segue with a segue class that I have written myself. The only thing that is different in my class is the perform method which I have put above. The segue is called through a button, and the prepareForSegue method is called only once.

[----- EDIT 2 -----]

I checked the viewDidLoad method of the targetVC and it is only called once per segue. Nonentheless, it would be much more convenient for me to use viewWillAppear, so do you maybe know a different way in which i can do this animation?

Comment: Check method `prepareForSegue` in your view controller, is it being called twice on triggering the navigation?

Comment: No, it is only called once.

Comment: Are you using any other methods for navigation?

Comment: It seems like you are presenting and your destination view controller after the animation is complete and also through your prepareForSegue method. I can't see the exact flow but I think that is causing the problem. If you have written a custom segue type feature then why are you using the default segue method.

Comment: I think may be your problem lies in `[sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view]`, it adds the destination's view to current view controller's view and then navigates to the destination view controller and recreates it's view.

Comment: is destinationViewController is a child view controller? Have you designed a Container view controller type scenario?

Comment: The ViewController that i am presenting is a completely separate screen. As sargeras mentioned, this behavior is probably caused because i first add the view to the sourceVC, and then present it, which technically shows it twice. I checked the viewDidLoad method of the targetVC and it is only called once per segue. Nonentheless, it would be much more convenient for me to use viewWillAppear, so do you maybe know a different way in which i can do this animation?

Comment: if you want to make your own transition than you have to write your own transitionAnimation. http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app this helped me. its in swift but should be no problem to do this also in objc

Comment: or you use the controllers function transitionFromViewControllerToViewController: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a Navigation Controller in my app, so i cant really use the transitionAnimation :) But I will look into the transitionFrom(...) method.

Comment: You should consider migrating to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and custom animator implementing `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

Comment: @Andy YES! This is exactly it. This solutions is much better, and realiable. Please refacor your comment into an answer with some more hints for other people (as i have already made research), and i will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` which are the more appropriate conventions to use for transitions since iOS 7.0. Since iOS 8.0 you also gain `UIPresentationController` support which allows you to build even richer transitions.

Example:

```
@interface ModalTransitionAnimator : NSObject<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint originatingPoint;

@end

@implementation ModalTransitionAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.25;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];
    UIView* sourceView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];
    UIView* destinationView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey];
    UIView* container = transitionContext.containerView;

    [container addSubview:destinationView];

    CGPoint originalCenter = destinationView.center;

    destinationView.center = CGPointMake(self.originatingPoint.x * 3, self.originatingPoint.y);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            destinationView.center = originalCenter;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
}

@end
```

Then in `prepareForSegue` you simply assign transitioning delegate and implement `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to return appropriate animators for presentation or dismissal.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController* controller = (UIViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    controller.transitioningDelegate = self;
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    controller.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    ModalTransitionAnimator *animator = [[ModalTransitionAnimator alloc] init];
    animator.originatingPoint = /* ... */;

    return animator;
}

@end
```

Since this is a modal transition, you have to use `presentViewController:animated:` when presenting controllers with it. Therefore use normal "show" segues in Storyboards and they will automatically run all animations under the hood, no need to reinvent segues here.

I had example of how to build custom transitions somewhere on Github:

https://github.com/pronebird/CustomModalTransition/tree/ios8